# Use np.nditer as zip

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have tried to apply the function `np.nditer()` like `zip()` with arrays of different dimensions, where the iterator should use only the first dimensions.

**Minimal example**

```py
a_all = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
idx_all = np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)

for a, idx in np.nditer([a_all, idx_all]):
    print((a, idx))
```

Which throws the error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,3,2)
```

**My use case**

I have two arrays with data which I want to calculate each other. Furthermore I have an index list for another array. So I try:

```py
a_all = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
b_all = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
idx_all = (
    ((0,0), (0,1), (0,2)),
    ((1,0), (1,1), (1,2))
)
result = np.zeros((2,3))

for a, b, idx in np.nditer([a_all, b_all, idx_all]):
    result[idx] += a*b
```

Which throws the same error like the minimal example.

I assume the problem is that `np.nditer()` tries to iterate over all dimensions of `idx_all`, but I couldn't figure out how to limit it to the first two.

`zip()` I do not want to use, otherwise I would need two loops:

```py
for a_, b_, idx_ in zip(a_all, b_all, idx_all):
    for a, b, idx in zip(a_, b_, idx_):
        result[idx] += a*b
```

**More sensible example**

```py
a_all = np.random.randn(2,3)
b_all = np.random.randn(2)
idx_all = (
    ((1,1), (2,2))
)
result = np.zeros(2)

for a, b, idx, res in np.nditer([a_all, b_all, idx_all, result], op_flags=['readwrite']):
    res += a[idx] + b
```

Comment: Can you give a better example? It looks like `result = a_all*b_all` gives you what you want

Comment: My first response when I see a `nditer` question is "don't".  In most cases list iteration is just as good, usually faster.  `np.nditer` is best seen as a test ground for the real implementation in C or cython.  That said, you may have a specialize use where it is genuinely useful, but I don't have time to study that now.

Comment: @mozway I've added a more sensible example. Sure there exists a lot of 'work arounds' but I'm simply interested if it's possible using `np.nditer`, and I find this will be a nice solution.

Comment: put more effort into understanding `broadcasting`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first case, corrected so the arrays do broadcast together  (if you don't understand what I've changed, you have read enough basic numpy docs.)

```
In [14]: a_all = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3,1)
    ...: idx_all = np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)
    ...:
    ...: for a, idx in np.nditer([a_all, idx_all]):
    ...:     print((a, idx))
    ...:
(array(0), array(0))
(array(0), array(1))
(array(1), array(2))
(array(1), array(3))
(array(2), array(4))
(array(2), array(5))
(array(3), array(6))
(array(3), array(7))
(array(4), array(8))
(array(4), array(9))
(array(5), array(10))
(array(5), array(11))
```

`nditer` iterates in a 'flat' sense, passing single element arrays (0d) to the body.  It's not like `zip` which just iterates on the first dimension (or outer layer of nested lists).

`np.vectorize` (which I don't recommend either), does the same sort of broadcasting, but passes python scalar elements to the function instead:

```
In [15]: np.vectorize(lambda a,idx: print((a,idx)))(a_all,idx_all)
(0, 0)             # test run
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
(3, 7)
(4, 8)
(4, 9)
(5, 10)
(5, 11)
Out[15]:
array([[[None, None],
        [None, None],
        [None, None]],

       [[None, None],
        [None, None],
        [None, None]]], dtype=object)
```

`nditer` needs the same sort of performance disclaimer as `np.vectorize`.  It doesn't help, at least not when using in python code.  In `cython` it can be useful, as demonstrated in the larger `nditer` documentation page.

Also `nditer` inputs can be complex, as shown by the TypeError that your last example produces.

Your last example:

I had to change `idx_all` to array, not tuple, so it can be readwrite able.  Read the `op_flags` docs more carefully.

And we still get the broadcasting error.  It isn't iterating the 'first layer'.

```
In [24]: a_all = np.random.randn(2,3)
    ...: b_all = np.random.randn(2)
    ...: idx_all = (
    ...:     ((1,1), (2,2))
    ...: ); idx_all=np.array(idx_all)
    ...: result = np.zeros(2)
    ...:
    ...: for a, b, idx, res in np.nditer([a_all, b_all, idx_all, result], op_flags=['readwrite']):
    ...:     res += a[idx] + b
    ...:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,) (2,2) (2,)
```